# Pressing "back" key when a killed process was on the stack

Tags: android

I'm learning Android development and I'm a bit confused about how Android manages killing process when an activity is on the task's stack.
Let's say I have a task with 4 activities: A-B-C-D.

Let A,B,D be part of process P1 and C be part of process P2.

Let's suppose that while the user is interacting with D Android kills P2 since D needs a lot of memory. What happens when the user press the back key?

1) Since P2 has been killed and C is missing, B will be on the top (i.e. the stack becomes A-B).
2) A new process (let it be P3) is created and activity C is restarted (but of course its state will be the "starting" state)

Comment: You're not going to get anywhere trying to think of every obscure scenario. Just build your app and if there's errors you can fix them.

Comment: True, I was just trying to understand the process-task-activity stuff. I'm already developing some little applications, this question was just for better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is: 2) A new process (let it be P3) is created and activity C is restarted (but of course its state will be the "starting" state)

I've seen this happening in some scenarios, mainly with phones with low memory

Ger